# How to synchronize data with partly different timestamps in R

Tags: r, merge

I have data from different measurements of the same temporal event stored in two dataframes. The timestamps in the two dataframes are not 100% the same though. I'd like to merge the two dataframes by **synchronizing** them as well as possible.

This is `df1` (reproducible data below):

```
df1
       rec_time   gsr
1  00:00:01.902 2.513
2  00:00:01.905 2.513
3  00:00:01.907 2.518
4  00:00:01.909 2.524
5  00:00:01.913 2.532
6  00:00:01.916 2.499
7  00:00:01.918 2.513
8  00:00:01.922 2.500
9  00:00:01.927 2.513
10 00:00:01.930 2.513
11 00:00:01.989 2.513
12 00:00:01.994 2.513
13 00:00:01.996 2.513
14 00:00:01.999 2.513
15 00:00:02.004 2.513
```

This is `df2` (reproducible data below):

```
df2
    Start_Time AOI
1 00:00:01.905 Iso
2 00:00:01.914 Kat
3 00:00:01.925 Iso
4 00:00:01.930 Iso
5 00:00:01.991 Kat
```

As can be seen, sometimes the timestamps (`rec_time` in `df1` and `Start_Time`in `df2`) show the same time; more often though there are differences. Now for the merge, where there *are* differences, I'd like to put the rows from `df2` on that row in `df1` where the **time difference is smallest**. How can this synchronization be achieved?

The **expected result** is this:

```
df3
       rec_time   gsr   Start_Time  AOI
1  00:00:01.902 2.513         <NA> <NA>
2  00:00:01.905 2.513 00:00:01.905  Iso   # same time
3  00:00:01.907 2.518         <NA> <NA>
4  00:00:01.909 2.524         <NA> <NA>
5  00:00:01.913 2.532 00:00:01.914  Kat   # different time
6  00:00:01.916 2.499         <NA> <NA>
7  00:00:01.918 2.513         <NA> <NA>
8  00:00:01.922 2.500         <NA> <NA>
9  00:00:01.927 2.513 00:00:01.925  Iso   # different time
10 00:00:01.930 2.513 00:00:01.930  Iso   # same time
11 00:00:01.989 2.513         <NA> <NA>
12 00:00:01.994 2.513 00:00:01.991  Kat   # different time
13 00:00:01.996 2.513         <NA> <NA>
14 00:00:01.999 2.513         <NA> <NA>
15 00:00:02.004 2.513         <NA> <NA>
```

What I've **tried so far** is meager:

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x = "rec_time", by.y = "Start_Time", all.x = T)
```

This obviously only catches those rows that have identical timestamps.

**Reproducible data**:

```
df1 <- dput(gsr)
structure(list(rec_time = structure(1:15, .Label = c("00:00:01.902", 
"00:00:01.905", "00:00:01.907", "00:00:01.909", "00:00:01.913", 
"00:00:01.916", "00:00:01.918", "00:00:01.922", "00:00:01.927", 
"00:00:01.930", "00:00:01.989", "00:00:01.994", "00:00:01.996", 
"00:00:01.999", "00:00:02.004"), class = "factor"), gsr = c(2.513, 
2.513, 2.518, 2.524, 2.532, 2.499, 2.513, 2.5, 2.513, 2.513, 
2.513, 2.513, 2.513, 2.513, 2.513)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))

df2 <- dput(et)
structure(list(Start_Time = structure(1:5, .Label = c("00:00:01.905", 
"00:00:01.914", "00:00:01.925", "00:00:01.930", "00:00:01.991"
), class = "factor"), AOI = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Iso", 
"Kat"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be easier to work with the data if we first converted the timestamps to milliseconds:

```r
library(dplyr)

timestamp_to_ms <- function(t) {
  sapply(strsplit(as.character(t), ":"), function(x) {
    1000 * sum(c(3600, 60, 1) * as.numeric(x))
  })
}

df1$ms_time <- timestamp_to_ms(df1$rec_time)
df2$ms_time <- timestamp_to_ms(df2$Start_Time)
```

Now that we have the time in milliseconds in both data frames, it is easy to find the nearest matching timestamps and record them in `df2`:

```r
df2$ms_time <- sapply(df2$ms_time, function(x) {
  df1$ms_time[which.min(abs(x - df1$ms_time))]
})
```

This then allows a standard `left_join`:

```r
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "ms_time") %>% 
         select(-ms_time)

df3
#>        rec_time   gsr   Start_Time  AOI
#> 1  00:00:01.902 2.513         <NA> <NA>
#> 2  00:00:01.905 2.513 00:00:01.905  Iso
#> 3  00:00:01.907 2.518         <NA> <NA>
#> 4  00:00:01.909 2.524         <NA> <NA>
#> 5  00:00:01.913 2.532 00:00:01.914  Kat
#> 6  00:00:01.916 2.499         <NA> <NA>
#> 7  00:00:01.918 2.513         <NA> <NA>
#> 8  00:00:01.922 2.500         <NA> <NA>
#> 9  00:00:01.927 2.513 00:00:01.925  Iso
#> 10 00:00:01.930 2.513 00:00:01.930  Iso
#> 11 00:00:01.989 2.513 00:00:01.991  Kat
#> 12 00:00:01.994 2.513         <NA> <NA>
#> 13 00:00:01.996 2.513         <NA> <NA>
#> 14 00:00:01.999 2.513         <NA> <NA>
#> 15 00:00:02.004 2.513         <NA> <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a beautiful solution!

Answer (score 3):

using @Allan Cameron suggestion one can try the `library(fuzzyjoin)`

varying `max_dist`, you can get different degrees of accuracy

```
difference_left_join(x = df1,
                     y = df2,
                     by = c("ms_time"),
                     max_dist = 2)

       rec_time   gsr ms_time.x   Start_Time  AOI ms_time.y
1  00:00:01.902 2.513      1902         <NA> <NA>        NA
2  00:00:01.905 2.513      1905 00:00:01.905  Iso      1905
3  00:00:01.907 2.518      1907 00:00:01.905  Iso      1905
4  00:00:01.909 2.524      1909         <NA> <NA>        NA
5  00:00:01.913 2.532      1913 00:00:01.914  Kat      1914
6  00:00:01.916 2.499      1916 00:00:01.914  Kat      1914
7  00:00:01.918 2.513      1918         <NA> <NA>        NA
8  00:00:01.922 2.500      1922         <NA> <NA>        NA
9  00:00:01.927 2.513      1927 00:00:01.925  Iso      1925
10 00:00:01.930 2.513      1930 00:00:01.930  Iso      1930
11 00:00:01.989 2.513      1989 00:00:01.991  Kat      1991
12 00:00:01.994 2.513      1994         <NA> <NA>        NA
13 00:00:01.996 2.513      1996         <NA> <NA>        NA
14 00:00:01.999 2.513      1999         <NA> <NA>        NA
15 00:00:02.004 2.513      2004         <NA> <NA>        NA
```